# SQLAlchemy: How to convert string to date and it should be in a proper date format

Tags: sqlalchemy

I used postgres to execute the following code

```
SELECT t.heatid,
       TO_TIMESTAMP(t.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24SMI:SS,MS'),
       t.routecode_act                             
FROM t
```

But how to convert it with sqlalcehmy, especially this line `TO_TIMESTAMP(t.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24SMI:SS,MS'),`

e.g.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
sa.seslect([
t.c.heatid,
t.c.date ??? here I don't know
t.c.routecode_act
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special object [`func`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func) to  call SQL functions:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

sa.select([t.c.heatid,
           sa.func.to_timestamp(t.c.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24SMI:SS,MS'),
           t.c.routecode_act])
```

This will return a `datetime` object. For `2021-03-02 10:00:00` it returns `datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 2, 10, 0, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=60, name=None)`